# Crash on Start after Updated VS Tools Apache Cordova Update 3

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

Updated to latest version of VS Tools Apache Cordova 14.0.50925.4 Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova Update 3 [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2015/10/06/now-available-visual-studio-tools-for-apache-cordova-update-3.aspx).  When I try to run VS2015, it crashes and I get the following error.

[image]

I tried `devenv.exe/updateconfiguration` and `devenv.exe /clearcache` and it did not work.  I just tried `devenv.exe /resetuserdata` and I get the following error:[image]

I also tried the mef cache fix and it did not work.https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/22b94661-70c7-4a93-9ca3-8b6dd45f47cd

**-------------------Update 1-------------------------**

After a few restarts I was able to get VS2015 working.  I can now create new `TypeScript Cordova` projects.  However, when I open some existing projects `VS2015` crashes.  Here's the code for a project that had worked and is now causing VS2015 to crash. https://github.com/dbiele/TypeScript-Cordova-SystemJS

**-------------------Update 2-------------------------**

I am able to open one of my existing projects, but when I debug > android > Ripple I get the following error:  Note: When I read the error I updated my version of node to the latest and still encounter the same problem.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We looked into this issue, and there were two problems Dean was running into:

1. His NPM cache was corrupted and needed to be cleaned. This was solved by running: npm cache cleache.
2. The project at https://github.com/dbiele/TypeScript-Cordova-SystemJS contains some NPM packages. When Cordova opens the project it does an NPM restore and the source control provider hits the Windows MAX_PATH and crashes. We got around the problem by moving the project closer to the root of the drive. We've also engaged with the source control team to see if there's a fix we can make for a future update.
3. The CompatibilityChecker issue seems to have gone away. We should have fixed this issue with Cordova Update 3. If it happens again I would like to know.

Thank you for reporting this Dean!

Comment: To point 2. I ve the same problem with the large path length and npm packages, and it helps to upgrade npm to the newest version. i use "npm-windows-upgrade". maybe it helps with the "MAX_PATH" problem.

Comment: Unfortunately MAX_PATH is an OS level restriction and has been around for decades. Npm was designed to work on Mac  which doesn't have this restriction. Packages tend to hit the limit easily because of the way that dependencies are nested in the folder structure.